# WebStorm There is no locally stored library

Tags: javascript, jquery, webstorm

I'have been working on a project which totally works on jsfiddle.net . However, when i try to run this project in webStorm, i get two errors.

first : [image: document is not defined]

second : [image: no locally stored librarry]

Before, i post my question here, i searched on stackoverflow but couldn't find any solutions. I already did :

libraries:   [image: libraries that i loaded]

and my html codes :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Super Mario!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='myMario.css'/>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

why did u get these errors although i loaded libraries and succesfully defined source script in my html ? what should i do ?

Comment: have you tested in broswer?

Comment: how do you run your code? By opening HTML page is browser? Or?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Seems that you get the error when running your .js file directly, via 'Run file_name.js' in it's right-click menu, right? When doing this you are running it using Node.js. But 'document' can't be used in server-side scripts executed by Node.js. It is only defined in client-side javascript, i.e. when running in the browser via a tag in the rendered HTML, not the Javascript API engine running on the server. BTW, your .js file is not even included in your HTML page, as far as I can see from HTML code snippet...
2. This is not actually an error... WebStorm can't use remote resources available through CDN links for completion. Once it 'sees' such links, it searches for the corresponding library in ~.WebStorm9\system\extLibs\, and, if matching library is not found, prompts you to download it by showing this warning. 
   You can either suppress this warning or agree to download the library: hit Alt+Enter and then either hit the right arrow and choose 'Suppress for tag' or hit Enter to download.

Comment: it seems problem is solved . i just switched the order of these two lines

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='myMario.js'></script>


i guess my problem was that i was trying to load myMario.js before jquery :)

Comment: Is there a way to "tell" WebStorm which library my URL should match?

Answer (score 34):

You need to select this file link and click Alt + Enter to download this file to your library.

Screen from WebStorm:

[image: screen from WebStorm]

Comment: This solution is simpler and to the point. This helps me, rather than reading bunch of explanation that i don't know that will work or not

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since this issue is WebStorm specific.

Comment: Where is the location WebStorm downloads it to?

Comment: On Windows libraries are downloaded to user profile folder, for example in PhpStorm: PhpStorm2019.2\config\javascript\extLibs 
You can click F12 on the library url to open downloaded file

Comment: In PhpStorm (and I guess in WebStorm also) you can click ctl+B on the url to take you to the downloaded file.

Comment: @Hyrial (now?) you can hover over the URL and it will show you the full local path on macOS
e.g.
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2022.2/javascript/extLibs/[library-file]