# How to insert toggle switch on laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, button, toggle

I want to insert toggle switch on the admin panel. With my code, i am getting checkbox instead of toggle switch. What should i do to insert the button?
My code for the button

```
<td> <input data-id="{{$posts[$i]->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $posts[$i]->status ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: Please edit/clarify your question. It is incomplete and unclear. What isn't working?

Comment: I want to insert toggle status button in my admin dashboard. Can you help me with that??

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried (Full blade code / controller code / preview screen capture ...) that we could look?

Comment: Blade code    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.toggle-class').change(function() {
            var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
            var post_id = $(this).data('id');

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '/posts.update.status',
                data: {'status': status, 'post_id': post_id},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.success)
                }
            });
        })
        })
        </script>

Comment: Controller code  public function updateStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $pets = Pets::find($request->post_id);
        $pets->status = $request->status;
        $pets->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Status change successfully.']);
    }

Comment: @hazel, I guess you're missing including CSS\JS library files. Pls check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're missing including CSS\JS library files.

Check working demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Toggle switch</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: is it because those script link says error"there is no locally stored library for the HTTP link"?

Comment: I google it and looks like an IDE relative issue, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097611/webstorm-there-is-no-locally-stored-library

Comment: Please make sure you're including full links and scripts starting from `https://` protocol

Comment: I got these errors  util.js:232 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
oz.o @ util.js:232
js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE:55 Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

Comment: DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/_site_dashboard_free/assets/js/dashboard-free.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/dashboard-free.css.map